# How to retrieve the path where the Project folder exists in C#?

Tags: c#, selenium

```
public static void ReadingExcelSheetData()
{
    Console.WriteLine("GetCurrentDirectory Returns :" + System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
    Console.ReadLine();
    controller = new XlsReader(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\TestCode\\Config\\controller.xls");
    testData = new XlsReader(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\TestCode\\Config\\testData.xls");
}

public static void  Main()
{
        ReadingExcelSheetData();
        Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Here System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() returns E:\seleniumwith C#\myprojectsC#\Pluralsite\TestCode\TestCode\bin\Debug.

But we have our controller sheet at E:\seleniumwith C#\myprojectsC#\Pluralsite\TestCode\TestCode\Config  location.

I just want the path upto E:\seleniumwith C#\myprojectsC#\Pluralsite\TestCode\TestCode.
How to get that. Can someone please help me out.

Thanks,
Nilanjan.[image]

Comment: Try [get-files-from-custom-folder-inside-c-sharp-project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294344/get-files-from-custom-folder-inside-c-sharp-project?rq=1) and [c-sharp-deployment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241326/c-sharp-deployment-install-additional-file-in-the-installation-directory)

Answer (score 1):

`Directory.GetParent(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)` will return you fullpath to your {fullpaht}\debug\bin. Remember bin folder may or may not have your file depending if you have set the property "Copy to Output Directory" to either "copy if newer" or "copy alway." If in the event you haven't you can try something like

`Directory.GetParent(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).Parent.Parent` until it takes you to the desired folder location then you can append @"\config\controller.xls".

```
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
controller = new XlsReader(@"E:\seleniumwith C#\myprojectsC#\Pluralsite\TestCode\TestCode\Config\controller.xls");
testData = new XlsReader(@"E:\seleniumwith C#\myprojectsC#\Pluralsite\TestCode\TestCode\Config\testData.xls");
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Application.StartupPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property helps to find application startup path.
For your SO problem following code will work.

```
string exeFolder = (System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.StartupPath)).Substring(0, (System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.StartupPath)).Length - 3);
```